# How to add a page in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using iframe in popup box using jQuery . I need to change the `iframe` and each time I have to load a different page in that particular frame.

How to include WordPress functionality in these pages inside the `iframe` without using `add_admin menu` option?

This is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function () { 
    jQuery('#start').click(function() { 
        jQuery('#popup_container').css('display','block'); 
        jQuery('#popup_back').css('display','block'); 
        jQuery('<iframe />', { 
            id: 'contentIframe', 
            'class': 'iframe_container', 
            frameborder: "0",    
            scrolling: "no", 
            marginheight: "0",
            marginwidth: "0", 
            src: main_path+"box.php"
        }).appendTo('#iframe_cont'); 
        jQuery(".dashboard_tital").focus(); 
        console.log('ok');  
    });  
});
```

Comment: waht are you exactly trying to achive? is the iframe pointing to a page from the same website? or an external website? do you need the info in the iframed page?

Comment: Only a description is not enough, can you show your code? See [ask] and note that we have a dedicated WP site: [wordpress.se].

Comment: i need to load pages by this fuction plugin_url('custum_visual_editor/pages/xyz.php');  inside iframe

Comment: @brasofilo
this is my jquery code for iframe generation inside popupblock , and i am calling a popup from tinymce editor button.
`jQuery(function () {
 jQuery('#start').click(function() { 
  jQuery('#popup_container').css('display','block');
  jQuery('#popup_back').css('display','block');
  jQuery('<iframe />', {
   id:   'contentIframe',
   'class': 'iframe_container',
   frameborder: "0",    
   scrolling: "no",
   marginheight: "0",
   marginwidth: "0",
   src: main_path+"box.php"}).appendTo('#iframe_cont');
   jQuery(".dashboard_tital").focus();
   console.log('ok');
  }); 
}); `

Comment: There's not enough material to help you, see http://sscce.org. You say you don't want to use it, but research in [wordpress.se] for `add_menu`, there are lots of code and different techniques to do that. [This one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/71437/12615) for example.

Comment: @brasofilo
i figured out , what i actually need is to create admin menu page say `mypage.php`  and call that page inside iframe 
 `mainpath+"wp-admin/admin.php?page=mypage"`
but page has i am creating have adnin bar footer and link and it is creating a menu option in admin bar , how do get a blank blank page

Comment: The solution you're looking for is **not good**. I tried to adapt [this code](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/4490062), but what happens is that we need to load WP 2 times, and there are many issues of authentication inside the `iframe`. I'd suggest that you do simple HTML/jQuery `iframes` and use Ajax to pull and set whatever you need from WP database.

Comment: @brasofolio
i am new to stack exchange , so don't know how to write code here ,sorry for this....
n thanx  I got it ,but same prob i am facing that i am getting double pages
so as a temporary solution for this , i used some css to remove n hide some extra things from page just to complete my task